# Bring amount from one table into another table based on a condition and the same primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

I have an update statement where I would like to bring a value from one table into another table with the same PK. Basically I want to bring in the `AWARD` value from the `AWARD` table and populate it into the `TEST` table in the `AWARD` column only where `TYPE = 'CON'`. Need to do the same with the Date column.

The `Award` table can have multiple rows so the award has to be summed. I am using Oracle SQL Developer. Any help is much appreciated!

```
UPDATE TEST A 
SET A.AWARD = (SELECT SUM(B.AWARD) 
               FROM AWARD B 
               WHERE B.ID = A.ID  GROUP BY B.ID) 
WHERE TRIM(A.TYPE) = 'CON';
```

Current `TEST` table data:

```
 ID     TYPE            AMOUNT          AWARD       DATE
---------------------------------------------------------
7186    INSPECT     $942,164.81         
7186    CMP         $1,392,528.28       
7186    CON         $92,464,162.51
```

`Award` table

```
 ID        AWARD            DATE        
-----------------------------------
7186    $83,157,895.00    6/25/2007
```

Expected result:

```
 ID     TYPE            AMOUNT             AWARD            DATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------
7186    INSPECT      $942,164.81        
7186    CMP         $1,392,528.28       
7186    CON        $92,464,162.51      $83,157,895.00    6/25/2007
```

Comment: If there are multiple rows, which date do you want to use?

Comment: the dates should be the same across all the rows but just in case i would say the MAX date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using a direct UPDATE statement containing an EXISTS Clause

```
 UPDATE TEST T 
    SET (T.AWARD,T."DATE") = (
                              SELECT SUM(A.AWARD), MAX("DATE") 
                                FROM AWARD A 
                               WHERE A.ID = T.ID  
                              ) 
  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM AWARD A WHERE A.ID = T.ID )
    AND TRIM(T.TYPE) = 'CON';
```

Comment: this query works, thank you. How can i do the same to bring in the max Date?

Comment: Nevermind, i think i got it to work. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Manny . . . I'm confused.  You accepted this answer but it doesn't set both columns.

Comment: good catch @GordonLinoff I just realized the date column by your warning, and why the OP asked for Max Date is understood by me now :)

Comment: then just remove `GROUP BY A.ID` within the subquery @Manny .

Answer (score 3):

You can set both columns as:

```
UPDATE TEST T
    SET (T.AWARD, T.DATE) = (SELECT SUM(A.AWARD), MAX(A.DATE)
                             FROM AWARD A
                             WHERE A.ID = T.ID
                            ) 
    WHERE TRIM(T.TYPE) = 'CON';
```

Note the `GROUP BY` in the subquery is not necessary.

Note I also changed the table aliases so they are abbreviations for the table names, rather than meaningless single characters.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good use case for Oracle's `merge` syntax:

```
merge into test t
using (select id, sum(award) award, max(mydate) mydate from award group by id) a
on (a.id = t.id and t.type = 'CMP')
when matched then update set t.award = a.award, t.mydate = a.mydate
```

Notes:

- you did not tell which date you want to pick when more than one record matches the given `id` in the `award` table, so I used the latest date
- `date` is a reserved word in Oracle - I renamed it to `mydate` in the query

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a1c2f2ebd418e3ead998a3a949f26e02)**:

```
  ID | TYPE    |      AMOUNT |    AWARD | MYDATE   
---: | :------ | ----------: | -------: | :--------
7186 | INSPECT |   942164.81 |     null | null     
7186 | CMP     |  1392528.28 | 83157895 | 25-JUN-07
7186 | CON     | 92464162.51 |     null | null
```

Comment: this one didnt seem to work for me, im going to try to adjust the query to see if it works. Thank you!